# How to send HTML code via POST using django

Tags: python, django

How can I send html code via POST method ? now django cuts the part of my code. Should I use any filter ?

I have a simple form and am trying to check value using

```
print request.POST['htmlContent']
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean "cuts the part of my code"? give an example please.

Comment: add your `form` too.